# Maven is not using failsafe plugin for integration tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

When I run `mvn clean install`, for the `integration-test` phase it does not use the failsafe plugin.

However if i explicilty call the plugin to run the integration test, it works (`mvn failsafe:integration-test`).

How can I make maven use the failsafe plugin when I run `mvn clean install` during the `integration-test` phase?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quote from [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.11/usage.html):

```
To use the Failsafe Plugin, you need to add the following configuration
to your pom.xml

<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: yea, i was missing that in my pom

Comment: Official documentation is 404.

Comment: By the way, are these tests supposed to run by default when you do `mvn package` or something like that? Cause I seem to only be able to run them by doing `mvn integration-test` explicitly. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @svish (It's better to create separate question... in next time) Phase `integration-test` goes after `package` so when you binding failsafe plugin to runs during integration tests than they obviously will not executed during packaging. See more about Maven lifecycle: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html and http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to litter SO with tiny clarifications :p thanks for the answer :)